# Swiftkey - How to handle Auto Capitalization with URL and Email Strings

Tags: keyboard, swiftkey

I like a lot about Swiftkey. But after a few years of using it, some of the annoyances haven't been fixed and I haven't "eventually got used to" the nuances of it like I thought I might.

This one has me stumped.

Enabling auto-capitalization means typing out a web address, or email (or anything with a period in it for that matter), adds spaces and capitalizations throughout the string. Trying to get it to type out correctly, while the fragmented string is also changed to auto-corrected words is unimaginably infuriating.

So I gave up and turned off auto capitalizations, lowering myself to texting like an imbecile, all in lower case (because who's got time to hit the shift key - am I right?).

Enter a second bug.

Swiftkey, when I can be bothered manually capitalizing a word at the beginning of a sentence, seems to think I want that text saved to the custom dictionary. So, for example, the text: `Swiftkey drives me crazy. Absolutely throw my phone against the wall crazy.` Will result in the word `Absolutely` being saved to the dictionary. Next time I go to use `absolutely` in a sentence it comes in capitalized as `Absolutely`.

Enter a third bug.

Swiftkey has a neat feature where you can long press on a predicted word, and elect it not to be predicted again. Great, if it worked. Long pressing `Absolutely` and selecting this, removes the word from the custom dictionary, completely, including the original, correct word. Next time you go to type `absolutely` and type accidentally type `abbsolutely` or some other fumble, it is not corrected to `absolutely` because that word is gone. Instead something else is dropped in. `absolute` for example, or worse perhaps, your mistake goes in `abbsolutely`.

Ideally I'd rather use auto caps. And have some way to enter strings with periods better. But with it off there is an unacceptable series of bugs that I think need to be fixed.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The email thing is really annoying and it's shocking that it still hasn't been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

For typing a web address if you start typing with `www` (case matters here) and then hit period, the auto-capitalization does not work and you can normally type your URL. For other queries I think posting them at [SwiftKey's Support page for Android](https://support.swiftkey.com/hc/en-us/categories/200328712-SwiftKey-Keyboard-for-Android) would give you better responses.

Comment: OK that's good to know. Thanks for the response. What about typing email addresses?

Comment: @square_eyes: Regarding email addresses I don't have any idea.